# how to use chrmorandi\yii2jasper with yii2

Tags: php, yii2, jasper-reports

This is my action in the controller but it gives me this error:

```
Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! 
Try to output the command: C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\pay^^^\vendor^^^\chrmorandi^^^\yii2-jasper^^^\src^^^\Jasper/../JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter 
compile C:^^^\xampp^^^\htdocs^^^\pay/vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples/shipments_report.jrxml
```

// Set alias for sample directory

```
    Yii::setAlias('@example', '@vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples');

    /* @var $jasper Jasper */
    $jasper = Yii::$app->jasper;

    // Compile a JRXML to Jasper
    $jasper->compile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/shipments_report.jrxml')->execute();

    // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
    $jasper->process(
        Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/shipments_report.jasper', 
        ['php_version' => '7.1.11'],
        ['pdf', 'rtf'],
        false, 
        false 
    )->execute();

    // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
    $array = $jasper->listParameters(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/shipments_report.jasper')->execute();

    // return pdf file
    Yii::$app->response->sendFile(Yii::getAlias('@example') . '/shipments_report.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@` while setting the alias, change the following

```
Yii::setAlias('example', '@vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples');
```

to

```
Yii::setAlias('@example', '@vendor/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper/examples');
```

Comment: @SanojSilva can you verify if java is installed using `java -version` in console

Comment: yes i have installed java jdk 10 and it gives me the version also when i typed in the console @Muhammad Omer Aslam